# Where are the sources for LaTeX3 development in TeX Live?

Tags: latex3, documentation

I'd like to take a look at the sources for some of the LaTeX3 development to model after, but I'm having trouble finding them.  Where might I find the sources for `texdoc interface3`, `texdoc xparse`, and the like?

Comment: ultimate source is  http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with any other material in TeX Live, the sources are available inside the `source` tree. You can find them by using `kpsewhich` with the appropriate `.dtx` file name, thus for example `kpsewhich xparse.dtx` will give

```
<TL-install-root>/texmf-dist/source/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.dtx
```

In the case of `interface3`/`source3`, life is a bit more complex as this is constructed from all of the `.dtx` files for `l3kernel`. There are a few `.tex` files which do this, and these are currently uploaded in the `doc` subtree, so inside

```
<TL-install-root>/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel
```

As David mentions in a comment, you can access the [SVN repository via the team website](http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/), or the (perhaps nicer) [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror) if you are willing to risk being a few commits behind the burning edge (synch is currently once-per-hour with the SVN on a script running on the latter server).

Comment: Dang, I was so close too! I had tried `kpsewhich`, but I wasn't adding the extension (doing just `kpsewhich xparse`) which was giving me nothing.  :-)

Comment: Looks like GitHub one is not a mirror anymore - see actual commits in git missing in the subversion repository.

Comment: @AntonKochkov There better not be! We've got a two-way mirror and to my knowledge it works fine. There are a couple of commits that ended up not showing in `trunk` (the Git side did a branch and I missed it before syncing), but they are all there at the top level.

Comment: Just to be clear, to see all of the SVN go to http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/ (missing off the `trunk`), though good luck working back through the interface there. I'd suggest instead using the Git version, and getting the SVN revision numbers using the data added by SubGit (basically add `fetch = fetch = +refs/svn/map:refs/notes/commits` to your `.git/config` in the `[remote "origin"]` part)